# sockets.on not receiving messages in browser but working fine in nodejs console

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a simple script in place which receives message from mobile devices. My mobile devices emit messages using

```
socket.emit('spaceChange', {'ax': 3, 'channelName': '615362'});
```

and i am printing this in nodejs console using

```
socket.on('spaceChange', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

it works fine in nodejs console but if i use same code in webpage and open it in browser i don't receive any messages

Here is the code for my webpage

```
var socket = io.connect();    

    socket.on('spaceChange', function (data) {        
        console.log(data)
    });
```

I don't find any errors in console

Comment: Do you also have `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` in your webpage?

Comment: @mk12ok yes i have this included in my webpage

Comment: And `var socket = io() ;` ?

Comment: ...and, of course, you check it in the browser's console (sorry for asking such an obvious question) ;)